# Transform position of point form one perspective into another

Tags: opencv, transform, javac, perspective

I'm trying to convert the position of a point which was filmed with a freely moving camera (local space) into the position in a image of the same scene (global space). The position of the point is given in local space and I need to calculate it in global space. I have markers distributed all over the scene to have corresponding points in both global and local space to calculate the perspective transform.

I tried to calculate the perspective transform matrix by comparing the points of corresponding markers in gloabl and local space with the help of JavaCV (cvGetPerspectiveTransform(localMarker, globalMarker, mmat)). Then I transform the postion of the point in local space with the help of the perspective transform matrix (cvPerspectiveTransform(localFieldPoints, globalFieldPoints, mmat)).

I though that would be enough to solve my problem, but it doesn't quite work good. I also noticed that when I calculate the perspective transform matrix of different markers in one specific image of the video, i get diefferent perspective transform matrices. If I understood everything correct, this shouldn't happen, because the perspective is alway the same here, so I should always get the same perspective transform matrix, shouldn't I?

Because I'm quite new to all of this and this was my first attempt, I just wanted to know If the method I used is generally right or should it be done differently? Maybe I just missed something?

EDIT:

Again, I have one image of the complete scene i look at and a video from a camara which moves freely in the scene. Now I take every Image of the video and compare it with the image of the complete scene (I used different cameras for making the image and the video, so the camera intrinsics actually aren't the same. Could that be the Problem?

[Perspective Transform Screenshot](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/8241/stackoverflow.png).

On the rigth side I have the image of the scene, on the left one Image of the video. The red circle in the left video image is the given point. The red square in the right image ist the calculated point with the help of perspective transform. As you can see, the calculated point isn't at the right position.

What I meant with „I get different perspective transform matrices“ is that when I calculate a perspective transform matrix with the help of marker „0E3E“ I get a different matrix than using marker „0272“.

Comment: you need to be more specific than "it doesn't work".  When you say "the perspective is always the same here" do you mean the markers are in the same position?  Your camera intrinsics are always the same but your perspective transform depends both on the camera intrinsics and the change in position between 2 frames

Comment: Please have a look above. I added some Information and an image, that shows the problem.